# Delete with Inner Join

Tags: sqlite

I am performing this SQLite command:

```
DELETE FROM t1027 INNER JOIN translationsmain ON t1027.textid=translationsmain.textid WHERE translationsmain.osb=0
```

The column "textid" exists both in the table "t1027" and in "translationsmain".
The column "osb" only exists in "translationsmain".

I am getting a syntax error, but I am not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`I am getting a syntax error, but I am not sure why.`
Simply, because such syntax is **not allowed** by SQLite.

Use this syntax, instead:

```
DELETE FROM t1027 WHERE textid IN (SELECT textid FROM translationsmain WHERE osb = 0)
```